# Compiler Errors after updating Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2013

Using the Vs2013 preview, i created a c# webapp selecting MVC and WebAPI from the dialog. It compiled ok. If i update the references from the nuget package manager to the beta2 versions (include Prerelease), it then fails to compile. I get 21 errors, located in the AccountController.cs and the IdentityConfig.cs. I tried updateing to the latest nightly libraries which gave the same errors. Appreciate preview code is just that so start again from the template. Was wondering if anyone knew which reference i could avoid updating.

> Error 1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    115 29  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 2   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    138 64  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 3   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    151 29  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 4   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    152 64  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 5   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserName(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserName(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    185 41  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 6   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    249 52  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 7   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity,
>   string)' and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity,
>   string)'  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    286 86  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 8   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    338 61  vs2013bootstrap
>   **Error   9   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserSecretStore' does not contain
>   a definition for 'UpdateSecret' and no extension method 'UpdateSecret'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserSecretStore' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\Controllers\AccountController.cs    376 57  vs2013bootstrap**
>   Error 10  Metadata file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\bin\vs2013bootstrap.dll'
>   could not be found    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap.Tests\CSC   vs2013bootstrap.Tests
>   Error 11  The type or namespace name 'DbContextFactory' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 32  40  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 12  'UserSecret' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserSecret' and
>   'vs2013bootstrap.Models.UserSecret'   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 33  45  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 13  The type or namespace name 'EFUserSecretStore' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 33  27  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 14  'UserLogin' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserLogin' and
>   'vs2013bootstrap.Models.UserLogin'    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 34  43  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 15  The type or namespace name 'EFUserLoginStore' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 34  26  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 16  'User' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.User' and
>   'vs2013bootstrap.Models.User' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 35  37  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 17  The type or namespace name 'EFUserStore' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 35  25  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 18  'Role' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Role' and
>   'vs2013bootstrap.Models.Role' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 36  37  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 19  'UserRole' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserRole' and
>   'vs2013bootstrap.Models.UserRole' C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 36  43  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 20  The type or namespace name 'EFRoleStore' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 36  25  vs2013bootstrap
>   Error 21  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity,
>   string)' and
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.FindFirstValue(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity,
>   string)'  C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\vs2013bootstrap\vs2013bootstrap\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs 95  24  vs2013bootstrap

**UPDATE**
 If i start from scratch with the same template, and update just the MVC and the WEBAPI libraries to 5.0.0-beta2 (or 3.0.3-beta2 in the case of Razor). then my application still compiles. The updates which i havent applied are those which are all stamped with 1.1.0-beta2 and are named starting Microsoft.Owin.Security

**UPDATE2**
if i then add all the Owin security references it still compiles. Leaving two libraries

- Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Core which is currently 1.0.0-Alpha1 (update is 1.0.0-Beta1)
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework which is currently 1.0.0-Alpha1 (update 1.0.0-beta1).

If i update the first library i get the above bold error, if i then update the second i get all the other errors.

So appears these updates aren't compatible with the other beta updates.

Comment: it helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416915/updating-asp-net-mvc-from-5-0-0-beta2-to-5-0-0-rc1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think i have finally found the resource which [answers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx) this. There is an asp.net/vs2013 refresh which updates the templates to the beta preview of Identity and removes the breaking changes