# Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions' from assembly 'EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Updated from entityframework 6.0.0-beta1 to 6.0.0-rc1 and when logging into my MVC5 application i get the following error

```
 {"Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions"}
    [System.TypeLoadException]: {"Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.":"System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions"}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HelpLink: null
    HResult: -2146233054
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSetExtensions' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."
    Source: "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Store`1.GetByID(Object id)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserSecretStore`1.<Find>d__c.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserSecretStore`1.<Validate>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityStoreManager.<ValidateLocalLogin>d__20.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.
CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityAuthenticationManager.<CheckPasswordAndSignIn>d__22.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at BASRaT5.Controllers.AccountController.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\\dev\\BASRAT\\BASRaT5\\BASRaT5\\Controllers\\AccountController.cs:line 53\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(
Task task)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Task )\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass34.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__33(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerAct
ionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()\r\n   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult)"
    TargetSite: {System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TEntity] GetByID(System.Object)}
```

my csproj has the following references

```
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.Entity.Design" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
```

web.config

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
   </compilation
 </system.web>
```

this worked previously do i need a new version of the System.Data.Entity.Design dll? or change the assembly version in the web.config?

**EDIT:
[Sounds like Identity Framework guys need to release a updated dll to match?](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1368)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a few changes in the namespaces and moving types around. I have updated the sample from Beta1 - RC1 https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample
You can look at the following commmit to get the list of changes needed. I will add some docs soon on the project https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/commit/b09479a9e5c2d4ff16c459ce0e4105c5ac5302f4

Comment: hi @pranav rastogi, thanks for the updated code. I had problems with the previous project trying to make it work with my existing structure. Some documentation would be appreciated. incidentally when i replace the code in my project it creates the tables prefixed with AspNet, whereas the sample project they arent

Answer (score 4):

A refresh of ASP.NET Identity that fixes this issue and supports EF6 RC will be available very soon.

UPDATE: the new version is [available in NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/1.0.0-rc1).

Comment: just updated the new packages, getting lots of errors now IdentityStoreManager could not be found, IdentityStoreContext could not be found etc. Have some of the namespaces been renamed or moved?

Comment: A lot has changed between the versions - more info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441157/compiler-errors-after-updating-microsoft-aspnet-identity-in-mvc5

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when adding EntityFramework dll version 6 to my MVC4 project. Downgrading EntityFramework dll to version 5 resolved my issue!