# IdentityStoreManager could not be found after upgrading Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to rc1

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

After Upgrading Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core to 1.0.0-rc1 several errors appear in the AccountController.cs And AppModel.cs classes which are generated by the default MVC5 templates in Visual Studio 2013.

Are there any release notes to explain how to resolve the breaking changes?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Me too :) It seems like no docs have been published yet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update the following nuget packages:

- Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework version="1.0.0-rc1"
- Microsoft.Owin.Security version="2.0.0-rc1"
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth version="2.0.0-rc1"

Get these:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin version="1.0.0-rc1"
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb version="2.0.0-rc1"

Then you will still have a lot of errors in your AccountController.cs file.
But now you have the classes in your project to fix them, or you could get my AccountController.cs file which is fixed, well it compiles and the application runs, but there is a spot (commented with todo:) that I am not sure about yet.

You can download my AccountController.cs file from my sample project on github here:
https://github.com/onybo/Asp.Net-Identity-RC1-sample-app

Comment: This is what you need. Someone to select it as best answer.

Comment: checkout this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396871/could-not-load-type-system-data-entity-dbsetextensions-from-assembly-entityfr