# ASP.NET Identity External Login - How to get Google Token for API calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-api, asp.net-identity

Just tried out the new ASP.NET Identity login system and added Google as external login provider.
Login works fine, but I can't find the authentication token for further API calls like

json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + accessToken);

The only information I get back after a login is surname, givenname, email.
Can someone show me where the token is hidden in the result?

Or do I need to set some optins in my Startup.Auth.cs where "app.UseGoogleAuthentication()"
is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware the Google Authentication in ASP.NET Identity is OpenID based, so you will not be able to make calls to the Google+ API which requires an OAuth access token.  In order to do that you (or someone else) will need to develop a Google+ authentication provider for ASP.NET Identity which is based on OAuth.

For OAuth based providers such as Twitter and Facebook you can use the mechanism I described in a blog post at http://www.beabigrockstar.com/get-the-twitter-profile-image-using-the-asp-net-identity/ to retrieve and store the access token and then use that in subsequent calls.

**Update**: I have developed an OAuth provider for Google+ with an example of how to store the token and use it to make OAuth calls.  For more details see blog post at http://www.beabigrockstar.com/google-oauth-sign-asp-net-identity/

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You likely can do something similar to this question about how to store the facebook access token: [How to store/retrieve a facebook access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992397/store-and-retrieve-the-token-received-for-the-user-after-authorizing-with-facebo)