# Fetching oauth credentials after asp.net mvc Twitter OAuth2 login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, asp.net-mvc-5

After testing the [build-in MVC 5 OAuth2/OpenID providers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) I was able to create a website which allowed me authenticate myself using my Twitter credentials.

The problem I now encounter is that I also want to store the tokens (*oauth_token* & *oauth_verifier*) Twitter posts back, in the url, after a user has been successfully authenticated. I need these tokens so I can allow users to post details directly from my website to their twitter account.

After setting up the **TwitterAuthenticationOptions** (see below) in the **Startup.Auth.cs** I did found that the tokens that I'm after can be found in the context `(((context.Response.Context).Request).QueryString)` but parsing this seems an ugly solution.

```
 var tw = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions {
       ConsumerKey = "SecretKey",
       ConsumerSecret = "SecretSecret",
       SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
       Provider = new TwitterAuthenticationProvider() {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) => {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:twitter:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Twitter"));
                return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
            }

  };

  app.UseTwitterAuthentication(tw);
```

How can this gracefully be implemented? For Facebook I found a solution which actually retrieves additional information, this feel similar...

[get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx)

Comment: I have not used the MVC 5 OAuth2/OpenID providers in .NET, but when using other .NET twitter libraries to authenticate with twitter for application authentication, we provided a callback url (which was an MVC path) with an action that contained twitter's query string parameters.  



`i.e. callback url: http://<your domain>/twitter/authenticate  
public ActionResult Authenticate(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier, string denied)
{
   //you method body here
}`

Sorry for the messy comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good extension method in Request object. Add following lines in HomeController or controller wherever needed.

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims // Lists all claims
// Filters by type
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.FindAll("urn:twitter:access_token")
```

GetOwinContext will give you the Authentication object where you can find the user object and them the claims.

I found a useful post here [How do I access Microsoft.Owin.Security.xyz OnAuthenticated context AddClaims values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456008/how-do-i-access-microsoft-owin-security-xyz-onauthenticated-context-addclaims-va)

I modified as mentioned in the steps in the post.

### AccountController.cs

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        //New method call made here to persist the claims from external cookie
        await SetExternalProperties(identity);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }

//New method added to persist identity info
private async Task SetExternalProperties(ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        // get external claims captured in Startup.ConfigureAuth
        ClaimsIdentity ext = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        if (ext != null)
        {
            var ignoreClaim = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims";
            // add external claims to identity
            foreach (var c in ext.Claims)
            {
                if (!c.Type.StartsWith(ignoreClaim))
                    if (!identity.HasClaim(c.Type, c.Value))
                        identity.AddClaim(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query instead of QueryString and then use Get method to retrieve value from query string.

```
context.Response.Context.Request.Query.Get("oauth_verifier");
context.Response.Context.Request.Query.Get("oauth_token"); or context.AccessToken
```

Other thining to note is that you shouldn't need oauth_verifer to post data. [Look here at required headers.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) I suggest you to use one of [libraries listended here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) to interact with Twitter.