# How to know when OWIN cookie will expire?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, owin

I would like to create some kind of countdown timer based on the time the OWIN cookie will expire.  I am using OWIN with MVC 5 and from what I understand SlidingExpiration is on by default.  I do not use 'session' as I need this app to live within a web farm (I dont plan on deploying a session database).

Comment: Is this not possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All you need is to get hold of the `CookieValidateIdentityContext` during the cookie validation stage.  Once you get it, extract whatever you need and keep them as `Claim` or some other way that you prefer.

For MVC 5 with Asp.NET Identity 2.0, you need to perform two steps:

1. Define custom `OnValidateIdentity`, extract cookie information, and keep it as `Claim`.

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
       {
         AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
         Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
         {
           OnValidateIdentity = MyCustomValidateIdentity //refer to the implementation below
         }
       }
     }


     // this method will be called on every request
     // it is also one of the few places where you can access unencrypted cookie content as CookieValidateIdentityContext
     // once you get cookie information you need, keep it as one of the Claims
     // please ignore the MyUserManager and MyUser classes, they are only for sample, you should have yours
     private static Task MyCustomValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
     {
       // validate security stamp for 'sign out everywhere'
       // here I want to verify the security stamp in every 100 seconds.
       // but I choose not to regenerate the identity cookie, so I passed in NULL 
       var stampValidator = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MyUserManager<Myuser>. MyUser>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), null); 
       stampValidator.Invoke(context);

       // here we get the cookie expiry time
       var expireUtc = context.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

       // add the expiry time back to cookie as one of the claims, called 'myExpireUtc'
       // to ensure that the claim has latest value, we must keep only one claim
       // otherwise we will be having multiple claims with same type but different values
       var claimType = "myExpireUtc";
       var identity = context.Identity;
       if(identity.HasClaim(c=> c.Type == claimType))
       {
         var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(claimType);
         identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim); 
       }
       var newClaim = new Claim(claimType, expireUtc.Value.UtcTicks.ToString());
       context.Identity.AddClaim(newClaim);

       return Task.FromResult(0);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Access your `Claim` in your controller methods

   ```
   // since expiry time has now become part of your claims, you now can get it back easily
   // this example just returns the remaining time in total seconds, as a string value
   // assuming this method is part of your controller methods

   public string RemainingTime()
   {
     var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
     var claimType = "myExpireUtc";  //NOTE: must be the same key value "myExpireUtc" defined in code shown above

     if(identity != null && identity.HasClaim(c=> c.Type == claimType))
     { 
       var expireOn = identity.FindFirstValue(claimType); 

       DateTimeOffset currentUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
       DateTimeOffset? expireUtc = new DateTimeOffset(long.Parse(expireOn), TimeSpan.Zero);

       var remaining = (expireUtc.Value - currentUtc).TotalSeconds;

       return remaining.ToString();
     }
     return string.Empty;
   }
   ```

I use this approach to remind my application users to extend their session before session time out.

Credit to this post [How do I access Microsoft.Owin.Security.xyz OnAuthenticated context AddClaims values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456008/how-do-i-access-microsoft-owin-security-xyz-onauthenticated-context-addclaims-va)

Comment: Do you have a working project where this code runs? Struggling to understand what to do with ar stampValidator = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MyUserManager<Myuser>. MyUser>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), null); as I don't have User Manager class and my User class a merely a DTO

Comment: 'I use this approach to remind my application users to extend their session before session time out.' - how do you acquire the expiration time without extending it? Perhaps related - do you have slidingexpiration enabled?

Comment: That really helped me. But it is woth notice that `stampValidator.Invoke(context);` is awaitable and it should be awaited! I had nasty exception because of that ;)

Comment: A great idea but for me the claims are never persisted in my implementation and not available in a controller. I have to use _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(i.ClaimTypeName, i.ClaimTypeValue)); to save claims. I therefore added a static list of class instances that store the values keyed on a user name. This is probably not the way to go on a web farm, but storing an encrypted record in a database is an option

Comment: @phyo do you know how to extend the session expiry once it is actually expired?

Comment: @afr0 - I set ```SlidingExpiration``` to ```true``` for ```CookieAuthenticationOptions```.  Doing so will extend cookie's expiry time when user make new HTTP requests during the second half of his/her session time.  But if the form-authentication-cookie is actually expired, user has to login again.

Comment: @Phyo agree on that part and SlidingExpiration is true by default as well. form-authentication-cookie is that different from OWIN-Cookie? should these two be used together?

Comment: @Phyo why did you chose not to regenerate the identity cookie? Currently I have the following code: regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie). Removing this (null) will have any impact?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to build on the first answer, i had problems getting it to work as i was using a custom user store. though the implementation seems simpler for myself

```
public static class ApplicationCookieValidateIdentityContext
    {
        public static Task ApplicationValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
        {          
            var identity = context.Identity;

            if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type ==  "expires"))
            {
                var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst( "expires");
                identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
            }

            if (context.Properties.ExpiresUtc == null) return Task.FromResult(0);

            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("expires", context.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString()));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

I also created a filter that adds the expiration to a cookie

```
// make sure its defaulted because the claim is not set on the login callback
var expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(
    Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeInMinutes"]));


if (identity.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "expires"))
{
    expires = DateTimeOffset.Parse(identity.FindFirstValue("expires"));
}

cookieHeaderValues.Add(new SessionCookeHeaderValue("expiresAt", expires.ToString("O"), expires));
```

Comment: I have a solution that takes the `SlidingExpiration` into account

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59038642/338456