# MVC 5 OWIN Authentication (Google Scopes) / Identity without EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity

As i read here, it is possible to add scopes to the facebook authentication method ([How to access Facebook private information by using ASP.NET Identity (OWIN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin)).

My requirement is to request additional scopes from google (e.g. "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email").

In my current MVC4 App this is realized with a custom OAuth2Client and the SimpleMembership Provider (custom Nhibernate implementation).

Futhermore, is it possible to create a custom ASP.NET Identity implementation without Entity Framework? Im not very confident with two different technologies (Nhibernate, EF) accessing my database.

Comment: I'm also looking to switch from EF to NHibernate with MVC 5's Identity... Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: It's eminently possible with the RTM build - it was much harder with the beta builds. I prototyped a library to do it, but it's not ready for prime-time yet and I don't have time to work on it right now. There's another implementation here - https://github.com/milesibastos/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity - it's also available as a NuGet package. I haven't tried it myself but it looks simple enough to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been looking into this and it doesn't seem to me that there is anyway to handle this from the existing nuget package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.

I was able to get scope crudely working by downloading the source from Codeplex, http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google/GoogleAuthenticationHandler.cs, and recompiling it. I added three lines in to the authorization endpoint in GoogleAuthenticationHanlder:

```
"&openid.ns.ext2=" + 
Uri.EscapeDataString("http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0") +
"&openid.ext2.consumer=" + 
Uri.EscapeDataString(requestPrefix.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "")) +
"&openid.ext2.scope=" +
Uri.EscapeDataString("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")  
                    ;
```

The third line is the scopes, and really should be added as a property on the GoogleAuthenticationOptions, and the concatenated into a space delimited list of scopes.

In any case, the addition above was working for me. Hopefully someone will put this together into a more comprehensive nuget package (handling refresh tokens, etc.). I might try myself if no one else does.