# How to get user id and email with Facebook authentication through Owin?

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I want to be able to login with Facebook and then retrieve the user `ID` and `email`.

I am using `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` to get the user login information, but it only returns the username.

Before `Owin` I had `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult` and it had a Dictionary with extra information, so I could grab for example

```
result.ExtraData.TryGetValue("name", out aux);
```

Now with `Owin` I don't know how to grab this information. How can I get the user email from Facebook, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access information returned by facebook after successful authentication you can try to implement the OWIN facebook middleware's provider method like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin). You can also request for additional information from facebook by adding more scopes.