# Facebook C# SDK With Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC. I'm Using MVC 5' built in Asp.Net IDENTITY provider for oAuth authorization by which users can log in through Facebook. But now I want to do more than that, I want to get the users access tokens and make users able to search in facebook, load their picture into database make their profile, make them able to post to facebook timeline, etc. 
I downloaded the Facebook C# SDK but can not find good simple tutorials for that, Are there any tutorials or sample codes for that Please?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: If you can answer here how to do more, that would be awesome @SonerGönül

Comment: Maybe this SO question may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin

Comment: Thank You @Konamiman I'll try to implement this...

Answer (score 2):

Are you not interested in using the Javascript API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

Over the years I always tried to simplify using a C# wrapper/SDL of some sort. At the end of the day I have always found the native JS API to be the best.

**Edit:**

In that case I would recommend the Facebook SDK for .Net: http://facebooksdk.net/

Here is a super simple getting started overview: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

Comment: I'm not very good in JavaScript And Secondly I'm making a Asp.Net MVC 5 Application so i'll use C# in it. As I'm better in C#

Also, I had read the Facebook documentation, I understood it, but I dont know how to implement these functionality in C# or MVC 5 Application