# OWIN social facebook provider will not list public profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, owin

I making a facebook login using the new setup in ASPNET mvc 5. When the user login I can see that there is a request for the default public profile, but all I'm getting back is the token, username and nothing else.

I thought that by default I would also get information like first and lastname. And if added to the scope also the email.

On the callback from facebook I'm having this code to extract the information:

```
var authManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var loginInfo = await authManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Thanks to the comment, I was able to find out that I needed to look into the identity of the callback to get the requested information

```
            var loginIdentity = await authManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

This will provide everything beside the logintoken/provider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin

Comment: Thanks found my answer there, will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to look at the ExternalIdentity and not the ExternalLoginInfo. The post is updated with this info. Also important to add email to the scope