# Access email address in the OAuth ExternalLoginCallback from Facebook v2.4 API in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

With v2.3 of the Facebook API, provided the following was set, the users email address would be returned on the callback to `ExternalLoginCallback`;

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "XXX",
    AppSecret = "XXX",
    Scope = { "email" }
});
```

However, any app that can only target v2.4 (released 8 July) no longer returns the email address to the `ExternalLoginCallback`.

I think this may possibly be related to the v2.4 changes as listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes);

> **Declarative Fields**
>
> To try to improve performance on mobile networks,
>   Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the
>   field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, `GET
>   /v2.4/me/feed` no longer includes likes and comments by default, but
>   `GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes` will return the data. For more
>   details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

How can I access this email address now?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To resolve this I had to install the [Facebook SDK for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/) from nuget and query the email address separately.

In the `ExternalLoginCallback` method, I added a conditional to populate the email address from the Facebook Graph API;

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

if (loginInfo == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}

// added the following lines
if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Facebook")
{
    var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var access_token = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
    var fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); // specify the email field
    loginInfo.Email = myInfo.email;
}
```

And to get the `FacebookAccessToken` I extended `ConfigureAuth`;

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "XXX",
    AppSecret = "XXX",
    Scope = { "email" },
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = context =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, what is the name of that Facebook library nuget that you used? I would love to know. thanks.

Comment: Great! it worked. now I'm trying to get other values user_birthday - any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Yovav check out [the api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).  It says you have to list all the fields you want back, so I guess if you changed the request to `/me?fields=email,birthday` you'd get the email and the birthday in the response.

Comment: Thank you @StaffordWilliams. I scoured the web to find this!

Comment: Very useful hack, thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: Thanks a lot @StaffordWilliams

Comment: @StaffordWilliams Excellent explanation. Can you help me a little bit more. If I need more information what can I do? like whole name , phone number, friend list, etc etc etc...

Comment: I can confirm that this still works in 2017 as I am the first to comment this year :))) Using all the (almost) latest stuff too - vs 2015 Community, Asp.Net 4.6.1

Comment: Hello, at dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email"); I get following error: (GraphMethodException - #100) API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument

Comment: Very Helpful, Thanks buddy!

Comment: Nov 2017 - loginInfo is always null - so your example doesn't work - this is with a vanilla MVC sample project. Is this due to API changes - how to fix?

Answer (score 14):

In MVC 6 (Asp.net Core 1.0), by configuring FacebookAuthentication in startup.cs like this:

```
         app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                options.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name";
            });
```

I could get the email. I.e:

```
   var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
   var email = info.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

Comment: Your example is for [tag:asp.net-mvc-6].  Additionally, I found that for [tag:asp.net-mvc-6] I did not have to add `email` to the scope, it was available by default.

Comment: I am sorry for that. ASP.NET 5/Core 1 and MVC 6 still does get a mess in my head.

Comment: Actually i found that this solution also worked for MVC 5 - specifically adding the UserInformationEndpoint above was the key to get the email to be populated

Comment: i am working with mvc5 and i want to get user name after fb auth. would you please give me some direction. thanks

Comment: Does this work on Asp 2.2 ?