# ASP.Net Identity and Mcirosoft external login issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I am learning Identity and OWIN. I have already implemented Google and Facebook login. Now i am trying to implement Microsoft login and

- Email is null
- No personal information like first name, last name, location etc

Facebook had the similar issue and following helped with getting the data:

[Access email address in the OAuth ExternalLoginCallback from Facebook v2.4 API in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714500/access-email-address-in-the-oauth-externallogincallback-from-facebook-v2-4-api-i?lq=1)

and

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

How can i get the data back from Microsoft?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email, you need to add the scope `"wl.emails"`. To access the rest of the data, you need to add claims so that you can get at it from your controller.

In `Startup.Auth.cs` you need something like:

```
var msaccountOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = /* client id */,
    ClientSecret = /* client secret */,
    Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:microsoftaccount:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Microsoft"));
            foreach (var x in context.User)
            {
                var claimType = string.Format("urn:microsoftaccount:{0}", x.Key);
                string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, XmlSchemaString, "Microsoft"));

            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
msaccountOptions.Scope.Add("wl.emails");
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(msaccountOptions);
```

Then, in your controller action, you can access the user details like:

```
var identity = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var firstNameClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.EndsWith("first_name"));
var firstName = firstNameClaim != null ? firstNameClaim.Value : null;
```

You'll need to consult the API documentation to determine the proper claim values for the service you're using.