# Version Deprecation Facebook Graph API v2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5

our Facebook Login is not working right now. We have received a message from Facebook Developer Portal:

> "Name of app" currently has access to Graph API v2.2 which will reach the end of its
>   2-year lifetime on 27 March, 2017. To ensure a smooth transition,
>   please migrate all calls to Graph API v2.3 or higher.
>
> To check if your app will be affected by this upgrade you can use the
>   Version Upgrade Tool. This will show you which calls, if any, are
>   affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in newer
>   versions. If you do not see any calls, your app may not be affected by
>   this change.
>
> You can also use our changelog to see the full list of changes in all
>   Graph API versions.

We are using ASP.NET MVC 5, and we are using or authentication like this:

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "****",
                AppSecret = "****",
                AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
                Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = async ctx => ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, ctx.User["email"].ToString()))
                }
            };

            facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
```

But today, our login info object, is null in ExternalLoginCallback:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [RequireHttps]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (loginInfo == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");
                }
... more code here...
```

In Facebook Dev. Portal our API Version is 2.3

We have tested many options, with no results:

[Access email address in the OAuth ExternalLoginCallback from Facebook v2.4 API in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714500/access-email-address-in-the-oauth-externallogincallback-from-facebook-v2-4-api-i)

[Why new fb api 2.4 returns null email on MVC 5 with Identity and oauth 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059384/why-new-fb-api-2-4-returns-null-email-on-mvc-5-with-identity-and-oauth-2)

Thank you much for the help.

Comment: See the solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working the answer of sammy34

Comment: @MarcHägele thank you, after following your link, I was able to solve my problem thanks to sammy34's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and here is how I managed to fix it and get the email from Facebook.

- Update following NuGet Pacakges

  - `Microsoft.Owin` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` to version `3.1.0-rc1`
  - `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook` to version `3.1.0-rc1`

Then add the following code to the `Identity Startup` class

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "your app id",
            AppSecret = "your app secret",
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name",
            Scope = { "email" }
        };

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

This is the definition class for `FacebookBackChannelHandler()`:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Replace the RequestUri so it's not malformed
        if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
        {
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is totally the complete solution i have implemented, good point

Comment: This is incredible...bad bad OWIN team...gonna try, come back to you later, My app is dead because of this

Comment: @user3012760 is necesary the package actualization? because RC1 packages for spanish language are still not available....

Answer (score 0):

Just update all the reference related to OWIN
The latest OWIN version is 3.1.0rc1.

This fix the login button, NOT the email, I cannot figure out these issue.

Comment: It fixes the login-button specifically because Facebook has updated the response type of the authentication token request to JSON, which MS Owin 3.0.1 could not handle.

Comment: I have updated to rc1 and it fixed. But I need to insert the code of one answer

Comment: nice, I will look on that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant update OWIn packages because of language packages (as my case) you can

1. Modify the Identity Startup class code:

   ```
   var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
   {
       AppId = "your app id",
       AppSecret = "your app secret",
       BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
       UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name",
       Scope = { "email" }
   };

   app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
   ```
2. This is the definition class for FacebookBackChannelHandler():

   ```
   public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
   {
       protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       {
           if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
           {
               request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
           }

           var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
           if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
           {
               return result;
           }

           var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           var facebookOauthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookOauthResponse>(content);

           var outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
           outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.access_token), facebookOauthResponse.access_token);
           outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.expires_in), facebookOauthResponse.expires_in + string.Empty);
           outgoingQueryString.Add(nameof(facebookOauthResponse.token_type), facebookOauthResponse.token_type);
           var postdata = outgoingQueryString.ToString();

           var modifiedResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
               Content = new StringContent(postdata)
           };

           return modifiedResult;
       }
   }

   private class FacebookOauthResponse
   {
       public string access_token { get; set; }
       public long expires_in { get; set; }
       public string token_type { get; set; }
   }
   ```