# Retrieving users Facebook email on OWIN login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I am learning how to work with OWIN external auth using the default MVC template in VS 2015. I enabled Facebook auth and added the scope "email", expecting the user's email to be returned by Facebook after the user is authenticated (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin)). Still, there is no email in the context.User JSON object and context.Email is also null.

This is the relevant code in Startup.Auth.cs

```
var facebookOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "XXXXXX",
            AppSecret = "XXXXXX",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated =  context =>
                {
                    // Retrieve the OAuth access token to store for subsequent API calls
                    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;

                    // Retrieve the username
                    var facebookUserName = context.UserName;

                    // WHY IS IT EMPTY?
                    var facebookEmail = context.Email;

                    // You can even retrieve the full JSON-serialized user
                    var serializedUser = context.User;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };

        facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

Any ideas what is missing? Why is the facebook email address not being returned?

Comment: Potentially useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32636149/3130094

Comment: Thanks @JamieDunstan - that was helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there has been a breaking change in Facebook API v 2.4 where you have to specify fields you want to retrieve. The graph request used to be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token=XXXXX
```

but for performance reasons as of FB API v2.4 you also have to specify fileds you want to retrieve within the scope:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token=XXXXX
```

Microsoft FB client implementation by default attaches access_token to the query string as "?access_token" which leads to the broken request (extra question mark ):

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email?access_token=XXXXX

So, to remedy that we need to use a custom BackchannelHttpHandler. First, we create the endpoint class:

```
    public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And then we provide it in facebook auth options along with explicitly specifying UserInformationEndpoint:

```
var facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"],
            AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppSecret"],
            BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
            UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email",
            Scope = { "email" }
            <.....>
        };
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636149/3130094