# ASP.Net MVC Get more information from external logins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api

I have an asp.net MVC web application and i try to add some fields from the external login providers, so that i would make it easier for my users to register for the first time.

How can i receive more information like birth-date, languages, etc?

(For now, everything works fine. My question is only about how to receive more information.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Facebook private information by using ASP.NET Identity (OWIN)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942196/how-to-access-facebook-private-information-by-using-asp-net-identity-owin)

Comment: Above is specifically for Facebook but should give you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform external login using Google OAuth2 Sign-on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Comment: I know that.
The problem is that I wan't to recive some more information from google/ Not only the basic information that is provided by default.