# AuthenticationIdentityManager can't be found after updating nuget packages (vs2013 preview)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-identity

Been fighting this one all morning. Here are the links I have been pointed to and I am still having no luck:

http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes-(release-candidate)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18426574/1118218 (I did everything the accepted answer suggests)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419011/1118218 (same question as above, but the solution here did not work either, does not resolve the classes)

I installed the ASPNET web tools refresh. Restarted visual studio. Everything seems to build correctly except for the AccountController. It cannot find AuthenticationIdentityManager(and IdentityStore).

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
    {
        IdentityManager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore());
    }

    public AccountController(AuthenticationIdentityManager manager)
    {
        IdentityManager = manager;
    }

    public AuthenticationIdentityManager IdentityManager { get; private set; }
}
```

Any idea how to get this to work? All the nuget packages related to ASP.NET Identity, Owin, EF, and MVC are updated to the latest pre-release version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operation you are looking to achieve here? you can get the current authentication manager via

```
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

which will then let you do things like

```
authenticationManager.SignOut();
```

the AuthenticationIdentityManager and the IdentityStore classes no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

The AccountController you are using seems to be generated by an older VS2013 version. The easiest way to make this work with the latest ASP.NET Identity version is by creating a new MVC Project with individual accounts using the release version of VS2013. This will create an AccountController class that is compatible with the latest ASP.NET Identity assemblies. Then replace your AccountController with the one you just generated.